# Mathematica 10 Audio Export Issue

Tags: export, sound, scaling

**Summary of the problem:**
When exporting data as an audio file (AIFF/WAV etc.), there appears to be unwanted scaling and offset in the data such that the minimum and maximum values are forced to be -1 and +1. This issue has been tested with AIFFs and WAVs on Mathematica versions 10.1 and 10.2. This issue is not observed when exporting the data as a MAT file for example, nor does it exist when exporting as an AIFF/WAV in Mathematica 9.0.1.0.

*Generating a sample waveform*

```
fS = 44100;
n = Range[0, fS/2];
sampleWaveForm = Sin[2 Pi 1/fS n];
```

*Plotting it*

```
ListPlot[sampleWaveForm, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

*Exporting it as an AIFF*

```
Export["/Users/username/Desktop/sampleWaveForm.aiff", Sound[SampledSoundList[sampleWaveForm, fS]], "AudioEncoding" -> "Integer24"];
```

*Importing it as is*

```
importedWaveForm = Import["/Users/username/Desktop/sampleWaveForm.aiff", "AIFF", "AudioEncoding" -> "Integer24"][[1, 1, 1]];
```

*Plotting imported AIFF*

```
ListPlot[importedWaveForm, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

We see in the image above that the waveform is scaled by a factor of 2, and then offset by -1.

**Question:** Am I doing something incorrectly (like missing an `Export[]` setting), or is this a bug in Mathematica 10.x? If it is a bug, is anyone aware of it and is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The export uses the internal function `` System`Convert`AudioDump`ExportAudio `` which contains the code:

```
samples = Rescale[samples, {Min[samples], Max[samples]}, {-1, 1}]
```

A simple workaround is to temporarily alter the behaviour of `Rescale` while exporting:

```
Block[{Rescale = #1 &}, Export[...]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I created the linked question because I tried exporting using ListPlay which allows specification of a PlayRange, and thought it would help identify the Export[] function as the place where the rescaling was occurring (as opposed to the Sound[] or SampledSoundList[] functions). It was also a little frustrating to not be able to export AIFFs from Mathematica all of a sudden and thought I would re-post in the hopes that it would trigger a response. I wonder why exporting AIFFs has been made this way when exporting in Mathematica 9 was so straightforward. I have deleted that post.