# Loss of scale factor when reading/recording/rereading data in a WAV file

Tags: export, import, sound

I use recorded data from an acquisition system in a wav file containing 6 channels, all data are encoded with 2 bytes in Integer 16. I can Import the *.wav data file and get all data in a Sound object within {-32768,32767} range. When I Export the same file in a wav file (using the same Sound object to store the data) and reopen it immediately using the same Import function, I have a discrepancy in the data: they are different from the initial data (with a scale factor and an offset). I suppose there existsome fancy option to keep the same amplitude normalization before and after record but a am a bit lost in the arcane of Export and Import function. Can anybody suggest a solution to read and record the same wav file unaltered?

```
u1 = Import["AcqDev_0_6ch[ai0to5]_2500kHz_ai_000.wav"];
Export["AcqDev_0_6ch[ai0to5]_2500kHz_ai_same_000.wav", u1]
u2 = Import["AcqDev_0_6ch[ai0to5]_2500kHz_ai_same_000.wav"];
```

Below the 100000 first samples shown for channel 1 extracted in the sound object u1 and u2

```
{u1[[1, 1, 1, ;; 100000]], u2[[1, 1, 1, ;; 100000]]} // ListPlot
```

[image]

And the relationship between the 2 sets of data: a linear scaling & offet:

```
Transpose@{u1[[1, 1, 1, ;; 100000]], u2[[1, 1, 1, ;; 100000]]} //ListPlot
```

[image]

Comment: Christian, take a look at this previous discussion, which I think could apply to your situation as well: [Audio export issues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91649/mathematica-10-audio-export-issue).

Comment: @MarcoB: thanks, the workaround you posted in [Audio export issues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91649/mathematica-10-audio-export-issue) worked well.

Answer (score 6):

As stated above, and based on MarcoB comments, I tested the workaround proposed by Simon Woods in [Audio export issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91649/mathematica-10-audio-export-issue), and it works:

```
u1 = Import["AcqDev_0_6ch[ai0to5]_2500kHz_ai_000.wav"];
Block[{Rescale = #1 &}, Export["AcqDev_0_6ch[ai0to5]_2500kHz_ai_rot000.wav", u1]]
u2 = Import["AcqDev_0_6ch[ai0to5]_2500kHz_ai_rot000.wav"];
```

Below are the first 100,000 samples (they are superimposed, so I added a 0.01 vertical offset to separate them on the graph):

```
{u1[[1, 1, 1, ;; 100000]], 0.01 + u2[[1, 1, 1, ;; 100000]]} // ListPlot
```

[image: comparison with original and re-imported wave files]

And the relationship between the two sets of data is now unitary:

```
Transpose@{u1[[1, 1, 1, ;; 100000]], u2[[1, 1, 1, ;; 100000]]} //ListPlot
```

[image: relationship between the exported and re-imported data]

Comment: Thank you for posting this followup! I owe you an upvote, but I'm fresh out of votes for today. I hope others will show you some love in the meantime (hint hint :-)

Comment: Missing upvote applied!